# Blog permalink redirects to homepage channel?

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, links

I've been following Andy Johnson's (Shapingthepage.com) [tutorial](http://shapingthepage.com/journal/how-to-build-a-simple-tumblr-blog-with-expressionengine) on building a blog using EE and have been running into an incredibly frustrating issue where the permalink redirects to the homepage. Only thing I can see in the template debugging is this and can't really make sense of it:

```
(0.010170 / 7.26MB) Snippets (Values): FALSE|1|Bio Mechaniks|default_site|blog-test-entry-photo
```

The blog entry page I'm working with is here: http://biomechaniks.com/blog_entry/
When you click permalink for the non-video entry, you'll see it just sends you back to the home page. Per Andy Johnson's tutorial, I placed the following the index page for the template group:

```
{if segment_2 == ""}
{embed="blog_entry/.blog.main"}
{if:else}
{embed="blog_entry/.blog.article"}
{/if}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You aren't being redirected to the homepage. The homepage is being loaded instead of the entry template.

Are you working on a sub-directory of a currently online website? Why is your homepage `/blog_entry`? If this is really the homepage, `/blog-test-entry-photo` isn't the `segment_2`, but the `segment_1`.

Comment: Hi @RobsonSobral /blog_entry? isn't my home page, I mean the content that's loading is exactly the same content as my home page.

Comment: But it's only loading one entry and not the paginated list from the previous view.  So it could simply be that you're parameters for single entry view and multi-entry view are not quite right.  For the single entry, you could try adding url_title="{last_segment}" for example, to see if that pulls the right entry into the page.

Comment: Channel relationship issue. Problem solved. Since I'm new, I guess I can't 'answer' my own question? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Justin, would you mind describing what the relationship issue was so that people who experience this in future can resolve it please?

Answer (score 1):

Channel relationship issue. Problem solved.